# Ruby syntax to avoid nil input being returned as zero

Tags: ruby-on-rails

a Rails application has a sanitizing method

```
def mobile=(value)
  super(value.to_s.gsub(/\s+/, "").to_i) unless value.nil?
end
```

Yet, when submitting via console the following

```
User.last.update(mobile: nil)
```

the record was obviously processed `to_i` returning a 0

```
mobile: 0
```

implying that the syntax `unless value.nil?` is inappropriate. How should the method be expressed to no fire when the value submitted is nil ?

Comment: What is the value of `User.last.mobile` before the update? And do you have any database defaults set for the column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you're only calling `super` if the value is not nil, that means the value is NOT replaced when the value is nil.  So if the value contained 0 then it'll still contain 0 afterwards.

If you want to be able to set the value to nil, you should do...

```
def mobile=(value)
  super(
    value.nil? ? nil : value.to_s.gsub(/\s+/, "").to_i
       )
end
```